# Powershell Refresh Script

Tags: powershell, microsoft-excel-2013

This is a fairly simple script, but it doesn't always work. It worked once today, the first time I ran it. I believe it isn't opening the files in the path I specified on subsequent runs. I'm not seeing errors in the log output, so I'm not sure where to go from here. I have seen threads in this forum about adding the desktop folder to this path, which I've done: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile. I'm using a 64 bit version of Excel 2013.

Here's my script:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.displayAlerts = $false
$path = "C:\Workbooks"
$workbook = Get-ChildItem -path $path -include *.xlsx, *.xls -recurse;

foreach ($file in $workbook) {
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
$excel.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll()
$excel.ActiveWorkbook.save()
$excel.ActiveWorkbook.close()
}
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Remove-Variable excel
$error | out-file "C:\Scripts\log\RefreshLog.txt"
```

Comment: Can you see more if you change `$excel.Visible` and `$excel.displayAlerts` to true?

Comment: Why do you set `$workbook` to the collection of files, then change it inside the foreach to be the workbook returned from `$excel.Workbooks.Open`?